# Adding a counter to a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi
Does anyone know how I would go about adding a counter (i.e. 1/12, 2/12, 3/12 etc.) to this slideshow?

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-creating-a-slideshow

Also, I would like the option to have another button that takes the user back to the first image at any given point during the slideshow.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for creating a counter:

**New HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow-area">
  <div id="slideshow-scroller">
    ... slideshow holder html (same as in the example) ...
  </div>
  <div id="slideshow-previous"></div>
  <div id="slideshow-next"></div>
  <div id="slideshow-counter"></div>
  <div id="slideshow-reset"></div>
</div>
```

**Additional CSS**

```
#slideshow-counter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute:
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**Additional Javascript**

```
function updateCounter() {
    $('#slideshow-counter').html(currentSlide + "/" + totalSlides);
}

function showFirstSlide() {
    currentSlide = 1;
    updateContentHolder();
    updateButtons();
    updateCounter();
}
```

Then add `updateCounter();` in a new line after `updateButtons()` is called in document.ready, showPreviousSlide and showNextSlide

Also in the `$(document).ready()` function you'll need to add the following line: `$("#slideshow-reset").click(showFirstSlide)`

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to add a button that returns the slideshow to the start? - Thanks again!!

Comment: Have added function to 'reset to start' to my answer above, as javascript only. You'll need to add some css to style the `<div id="slideshow-reset"></div>` to get it to appear correctly and show some informative text/an image

Comment: Thanks Chris - really appreciate you help with this!

Comment: Hi Chris - sorry to bother you again. Is there a way to count only certain 'slides' with the counter? - i.e. I currently have 37 slides, I would like to break these down into catagorys/groups of 2/3 and sometimes 4. So the counter would only count the groups rather than the amount of slides. I don't think its possible but I'd appreciate an experts opinion... thanks again.